# Pandas visualize top 3 in the top 3 categories

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, data-visualization

I have a dataset like this: (basically a movie database)

```
title   Genre   ratinglevel userid  user_rating_score White Chicks  PG-13   crude and sexual humor, language and some drug content  80  82 Lucky Number Slevin  R   strong violence, sexual content and adult language  100 82 Grey's Anatomy   TV-14   Parents strongly cautioned. May be unsuitable for children ages 14 and under.   90  98 Prison Break TV-14   Parents strongly cautioned. May be unsuitable for children ages 14 and under.   90  98 How I Met Your Mother    TV-PG   Parental guidance suggested. May not be suitable for all children.  70  94 Supernatural TV-14   Parents strongly cautioned. May be unsuitable for children ages 14 and under.   90  95 Breaking Bad TV-MA   For mature audiences.  May not be suitable for children 17 and under.   110 97 The Vampire Diaries  TV-14   Parents strongly cautioned. May be unsuitable for children ages 14 and under.   90  91 The Walking Dead TV-MA   For mature audiences.  May not be suitable for children 17 and under.   110 98 Pretty Little Liars  TV-14   Parents strongly cautioned. May be unsuitable for children ages 14 and under.   90  96 Once Upon a Time TV-PG   Parental guidance suggested. May not be suitable for all children.  70  98 Sherlock TV-14   Parents strongly cautioned. May be unsuitable for children ages 14 and under.   90  95 Death Note   TV-14   Parents strongly cautioned. May be unsuitable for children ages 14 and under.   90  77 Naruto   TV-PG   Parental guidance suggested. May not be suitable for all children.  70  88 The Hunter   R   language and brief violence 100 88 Lottie Dottie Chicken    TV-Y    Suitable for all ages.  10  88 Arrow    TV-14   Parents strongly cautioned. May be unsuitable for children ages 14 and under.   90  96 Black Mirror TV-MA   For mature audiences.  May not be suitable for children 17 and under.   110 80 The Originals    TV-14   Parents strongly cautioned. May be unsuitable for children ages 14 and under.   90  74 The 100  NR  This movie has not been rated.  124 97 Masha and the Bear   TV-Y    Suitable for all ages.  10  81 Ãƒâ€œ Pai, Ãƒâ€œ - Look at This  TV-MA   For mature audiences.  May not be suitable for children 17 and under.   110 81 Nymphomaniac: Volume 1   NR  This movie has not been rated.  124 81
```

I wish to plot/visualize which Genre's are watched more more. Which I am doing as below and it is fine.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
df = df[['Genre', 'userid']].drop_duplicates()['Genre']
g = sns.countplot(y = df, order=df.value_counts().index[:10])
plt.title("Top 10 Genre")
plt.show()
```

I wish to somehow add three most watched title in each genre in the same plot or connected plot. I don't have a attempt on this as not able to visualize the best way to do visualization.

Answer (score 0):

Groupby I think is your friend here. `dt.Groupby(['Genre', 'Movie'])['userid'].count()` or something like it (adapted to your dataset) should group by genre and movie then count the number of `userid` under each group. Reset the index to convert the data back to a DataFrame and you can sort/filter all you want to get your answer.